# Multiple Ingresses with multiple paths - how are the paths regexes prioritized?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

When running multiple ingress controllers under Kubernetes with the same host, how are the Regexes evaluated? Does the order matter?

Basically, I have one ingress for the API and another for the frontend.

The API being on example.com/api/ -> api/(.*)

The frontend being on example.com -> (.*)

Does the order I deploy these matter? Since the regex for the frontend will essentially just be (.*), if this is evaluated before the /api/(.*) regex, all traffic will be sent to the frontend, which I don't want.

How can I avoid this?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions follow a first match policy.

Ingress-nginx orders the paths by descending length before putting them into the config.

So in your case it will match `api/(.*)` on the first place

Also, do not forget that you have to enable regexes with following annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this include when they're under multiple different ingresses? Do you also know if that information is documented anywhere? :)

Comment: @JamesB. no, for different ingresses it's not applicable. Each ingress has a separate ingress controller with it's own config.  Here is more information about path matching - https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/ingress-path-matching.md

Comment: Sorry, I meant for if you had multiple Ingress "objects". From the documents though, it looks like it combines them all. I couldn't find that anywhere so thank you very much :)